# Show that for compact $A$ and any point $x\in\mathbb{R^2}\setminus A,$ there is a closest point in $A$ to $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that for any point $x\in\mathbb{R^2}\setminus A$, there is a closet point $a$ in $A$ to $x$. (This means that the point $a\in A$  satisfies $\lVert x-a\rVert\le\lVert x-b\rVert$  for all  $b\in A$. It does not imply that $a$ is unique--it may not be).

Hint: Fix $x$ and define a useful continuous function on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ can be seen as $A\times \{0\}$, which is a compact sbset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.. Define a function on $A$ by $f(z)=d(x,z)$, it is continuous on the compact set $A$. Then it can attain its minimum on $A$.
The point attaining the minimum is required.

Answer (score 0):

The hint you have been given is a very good one.

Recall that a continuous function achieves a minimum on a compact set, so what function achieving a minimum would be useful to you here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A useful continuous function would be $d: A \to \mathbb{R}$ where d is defined as $d(a) = \mathrm{distance}(a, x)$.

You can say a little more about the image of this function and perhaps you can explore the behavior of of this function at minima and maxima.